# Matching time on iPhones worldwide - synchronizing playing video?

Tags: ios, iphone

Two Quick questions:

1. Are the **seconds** value of the clock/time on all iPhones around the world the same? If not, are they close at least & how close?
2. Do the **seconds** value of the clock/time on all iPhones around the world change/increment at the exact same time?

Upon request, I'm editing this post and adding the purpose for asking such questions:

I'm trying to make a corporate app that can play a video on multiple iPhones around the world at the exact same time (or as close as possible, ideally the **exact** same moment). Could you please guide me on how to do this?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: OP, I'm not sure of the answer to your question.  But just a tip, if you're trying to synchronize something, there are very well-established techniques for doing so in software engineering!  Maybe, you should also ask another question regarding what you are trying to achieve.  Good luck!

Comment: When dealing with time you have to be careful when you say things like "the exact same time" - Do you mean within a second of each other? Within a millisecond?  A nanosecond?  I suspect that most people will have their devices getting time automatically which means that they sync back to the reference clocks used for things like GPS, so they should be pretty close, but I noticed that my iOS devices are several seconds different from the networked clocks at my train station, which I would expect were also synchronised to something, so as @Fattie says, explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to make a corporate app that can play a video on multiple iPhones around the world at the exact same time (or as close as possible, ideally the **exact** same moment). Could you please guide me on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I am in Australia. The continent is too big and too sparsely populated to have a radio time system; but those systems just use the same time sources that drive NTP and the cellular network time source that most iOS devices use

Comment: Sure, anyway I answered the Question.  Feel free to ask another one, Enjoy!   (BTW note that Australia is physically smaller than the spread of the major time signal towers worldwide.  There's no reason whatsoever it could not be covered, we just happen to not have that in Australia yet.  Indeed the US is shoddily covered.)

Comment: You can't really trust time on a device that the user has control over. If synchronisation is really important then your app should check the time on a known server

Comment: @fattie we could cover the main population centres, but it just wouldn't be cost effective to cover everywhere.  Australia is about the size of continental USA and has about 26 million people. Taking the whole country into account our population density is 3.1 people per km2; obviously more in major cities. We have never had radio time and I don't think we ever will. I think it is basically an obsolete tech, with low cost GPS receivers easily available

Comment: hi @Paulw11, not a big deal but 1 or two cover all of the US, 1 or 2 cover all of Europe -  they cover large (continental-sized) areas.  they cost almost nothing. But sure, it's not something anyone's ever bothered to do in Oz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your actual question per se,

> Are the seconds value of the clock/time on all iPhones around the world the same?

The fact is, **yes**, 99.9999% of iPhone users simply use the "get time from a server" system which is of course built in to any phone now.

(Indeed, this simply applies to any Windows, Mac, Android, iOS, etc etc device.)

**Yes**, they are all "about the same".

You could rely on it being within a second or two, probably even closer.

You cannot rely on it being closer than that.

It seems that you

> I'm trying to make a corporate app that can play a video on multiple iPhones around the world at the exact same time

Synchronization in general and streaming video (is it streaming?) is a well-explored (and rather technical) branch of software engineering.  (For example a massive amount of game engineering, which is a huge field, relates to inside-the-frame synchronization.)

This is not something you can learn how to do in five minutes, and it requires a stack of device-cloud stuff. Go ahead and ask new questions about this, or just google to get started!  Good luck.

---

Regarding using push notifications.

With the push notification you would **send a time**. You would not send a "command to play it".

So say right now it is (example) 09:13:28.  You would pick a time in the future by a couple minutes.  So let's say 09:14:30.

Then using a push notification you would send that information "09:14:30" (and a video file name) to everyone connected.  (You'd be sending a "command" as it were, to play video X at 09:14:30.)

Then every device would in fact play the video at 09:14:30 (simply using the local clock, as asked in your question).

Be aware that sending push notifications is extremely sloppy and slow.  It can take any amount of time from 5 seconds to a minute, AND quite often there are delays beyond that (ie ten minutes or the like).

---

I personally would **not even bother** starting to experiment with push notifications, for the project you describe.

These days, making apps **is entirely about using device-cloud services**, such as **Firebase**.  Everything is about "OCC" - occasionally connected computing.

(So, you can't get a job "making apps" anymore - i.e. if you know how to move buttons around on an iPhone screen. You get a job because you can make a total, live, device-cloud system - indeed such as you are making.)

Indeed your example project is the perfect such "demo" project for learning about how to do modern apps.

Simply use Firebase to sync everything up.

You'll essentially put a piece of information on Firebase ("play video X at 09:14:30") and that information will be communicated fairly quickly/reliably to everyone connected.

For the particular task you describe, I personally would use **PubNub** which is faster than Firebase and basically made for game-like problems precisely like you describe.

http://pubnub.com

[image]

If you truly needed performance/reliability better than pubnub, you are really talking major engineering. So, the (buildings of) engineers who make live games at Nintendo, Warcraft etc, would tackle such an issue as "being *even faster* than PubNub".

---

## So, the answer in brief!

The very short answer then to your question posed is:

- Learn to use the various device-cloud services, which are at the heart of all apps today.  (Knowing how to make "an Android or iOS app", as such, is of no consequence today.)  For your particular problem, you'll want to use PubNub specifically, as it is built for precisely realtime problems such as this.  (Firebase more leans towards "OCC" type data problems.)

Really that's it.

Comment: Hey @Fattie thanks for your response! I am only making the app on users' phones play a video that would have been previously downloaded on to their phones. If this is the case, is there a quick path I can go down to accomplish this? Perhaps the name of the technique or a link you've seen that is relevant? thanks!

Comment: There's no quick path.  In fact **your approach is perfectly valid**.  You won't be able to sync it better than that.   Use Firebase is you need basic syncing capabilities, to launch them all at some certain time.  Good luck.

Comment: You could send a push notification to "unlock" the previously downloaded video. The notifications would probably be received within a second or so across all devices.

Comment: note @JohnPaoletto if you use a push notification. see my new edit

Comment: @Fattie thanks for your awesome answer, honestly cannot thank you enough for taking the time. Learned a ton, and now I'll go nail this project ;)

Comment: Heh, there is absolutely no need to thank me  :)  Enjoy SO.  Note that ably.io is another competitor who claims to be "fast like PubNub".   The very bottom line here though is .......... "You'd use PubNub for that."  If someone asked me or anyone experienced to do this task this afternoon, you'd just start off with PubNub.   On the PubNub site, navigate to their "live drawing" demo - it's great!  Enjoy!